# Sum of $k-tuple$ partition of $d$. $k$ and $d$ are both positive integers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, graph-theory, summation, integer-partitions

I am trying to understand this [paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81930229.pdf) by Bondy and Jackson and in it I found the following calculation in which I cannot figure out how we got from 2nd last step to last step. I have referred the paper for the further details of this calculation.

I understand that in the initial steps were are using power series after that we are manipulating the terms using partial fraction.

Here $c(k,d)$  is the cardinality of ordered $k$ tuple summing to $d$ and $2^{k-1}$ is weight of those tuples.

$\sum _{k\geq 2} 2^{k-1} c( k,d) \ \\
\\
\vdots
\\
=\ \left[ x^{d}\right]\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{2}{1-2x} -\frac{3}{1-x} +\frac{1}{1+x}\right)\\
\\
=\ \frac{1}{3}\left( 2^{d+1} -3+( -1)^{d}\right) \blacksquare
$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $[x^d]$ denotes the coefficient of $x^d$ in a series. We obtain by *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{[x^d]\frac{2}{1-2x}}=2[x^d]\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (2x)^n=2\cdot 2^d\color{blue}{=2^{d+1}}
\end{align*}
and similarly for the other terms.